# Amazon InApp Purchase

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

When we are implementing InApp by Amazon inApp API, we call the `initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequests(Offset offset)` function by Purchasing Manager. In response, we get `onPurchaseUpdatesResponse(PurchaseUpdatesResponse obj)`.

I am confused about offset. If we are calling for first time then we can use `Ofset.BEGINNING` and in the response the method `obj.getOffset()`. The documentation says that this will return the `Offset` you're supposed to send.

If it will return the old offset, then it means that the same `Offset.BEGINNING` will be sent every time.

Also, I am confused about what the `Offset` is in the first place.

Can someone clarify those points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [IAP Reference](https://developer.amazon.com/public/binaries/content/assets/javadoc/in-app-purchasing-api/com/amazon/inapp/purchasing/PurchaseUpdatesResponse.html#getOffset%28%29):

> `public Offset getOffset()`
>
> Returns an `Offset` that you ***can pass*** to
>   `PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequest(Offset)` if `isMore()`
>   indicates that more results are available.

In the [IAP Quick Start Guide](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs/quick-start#5.%20Sync%20Access%20Rights%20for%20the%20Current%20User), it said:

> If `PurchaseUpdatesResponse.isMore()` returns `true`, make a recursive
>   call to `PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequest()` with the
>   value returned in `PurchaseUpdatesResponse.getOffset()`.

@yasiriqbal776, I think you may have misread the documentation. Otherwise, can you please provide the URL to the documentation you're referring to?

Comment: https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/javadocs/in-app-purchasing-api-reference                                     Here above documentation of Amazon developer site,in PurchaseUpdateResponse their is function getOffset whose description is Returns an Offset that you can pass to                                     PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequest(Offset) if isMore() indicates that more results are available.                                     Now this show we get same offset which we send and what is for this isMore() method, i am confused here

Comment: @yasiriqbal776, the documentation didn't say getOffset() would return the same offset value as what you sent.

Comment: @yasiriqbal776, I would also encourage you to try the SampleIAPEntitlementsApp from Amazon Mobile App SDK if you haven't already. Simply build & run the sample, and then filter "offset" in logcat. It would show that the offset value from the PurchaseUpdatesResponse object is different from what was passed-in.

Answer (score 1):

For a particular user, the first time you call initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequests(Offset offset), you should call it with Offset.BEGINNING.  Inside the onPurchaseUpdatesResponse callback, you should check if there are more purchase updates and call initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequest recursively using the last Offset. (see code below for an example)

If you want to retrieve only "new" purchase updates, you can also save the last offset and make subsequent initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequests(Offset offset) calls starting from that saved offset.

```
public void onPurchaseUpdatesResponse(final PurchaseUpdatesResponse response) {

    //...
    Offset offset = response.getOffset();
    if (response.isMore()) {
        PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequest(offset);
    }

    // Save offset associated to this IAP UserId.
}
```

The sample app for entitlements in the Amazon Mobile SDK also includes example code that illustrates how to use the Offset as well.

Comment: here response.getOffset() method i told in explanation above that documentation said it return the offset which you send in initiatePurchaseUpdateRequest(Ofset); if it return what we send then does it not use OFset.BEGNING ofsets.

Comment: The offset that is returned in the PurchaseUpdatesResponse instance in onPurchaseUpdatesResponse is a different value than Offset.BEGINNING.  So when response.isMore() returns true, you will call initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequest with this offset that's different from Offset.BEGINNING so that you get the next set of purchase updates.  Just think of Offset as page numbers in a paginated response.